# Browserless web scraping of Vaadin based website in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm new with web scraping and I encountered a problem.

I tried to extract the list of the states from this site, 'https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:JP', by using Python, selenium and PhantomJS but I failed with the output as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;chrome=1">
  <style type="text/css">html, body {height:100%;margin:0;}</style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./../VAADIN/themes/obp/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./../VAADIN/themes/obp/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../VAADIN/themes/obp/styles.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="./../VAADIN/widgetsets/org.iso.obp.ui.widgetset.applicationWidgetset/org.iso.obp.ui.widgetset.applicationWidgetset.nocache.js?1444641834593"></script><script src="https://www.iso.org/obp/VAADIN/widgetsets/org.iso.obp.ui.widgetset.applicationWidgetset/913365F3A38F531CF0D09D8744F3A155.cache.js"></script></head>
 <body scroll="auto" class=" v-generated-body">
  <div id="obpui-105541713" class=" v-app obp">
   <div class=" v-app-loading"></div>
   <noscript>
    You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.
   </noscript>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
if (!window.vaadin) alert("Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js");
vaadin.initApplication("obpui-105541713",{"heartbeatInterval":300,"versionInfo":{"vaadinVersion":"7.3.10"},"vaadinDir":"./../VAADIN/","authErrMsg":{"message":"Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC to continue.","caption":"Authentication problem"},"widgetset":"org.iso.obp.ui.widgetset.applicationWidgetset","theme":"obp","comErrMsg":{"message":"Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC to continue.","caption":"Communication problem"},"serviceUrl":".","standalone":true,"sessExpMsg":{"message":"Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> or press ESC key to continue.","caption":"Session Expired"}});
//]]></script>

</body></html>
```

My code in Python is here.

```
from selenium import webdriver

target_url = 'https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:JP'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get( target_url)

print driver.page_source
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What PhantomJS version are you using? Have you tried using 1.9.8 or 2.0.0?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for your comment. :) I use 1.9.8 via npm.

Comment: it works on phantom 2.0.1. Try to update

Comment: @rmn Thanks. I tried but it seems I can't make it as my os is OS X El Capitan updated just a few days ago. Any alternatives recommended? I don't mind using other libraries and even languages to extract the information.